# How to make a login button with facebook account

Tags: javascript, facebook

i want to make a button like this stack-overflow.com website with Facebook account to log in my website,i am a new guy,and my English is not good,can u help me?

like this stack-overflow.com log in button

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides help for "Login with Facebook" on their developer page 
[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.3) or more specific for Websites [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3)

Basicaly you have to create a Facebook App-ID and include the Facebook Javascript SDK to provide "login with Facebook" functionality.

Comment: thanks,i had created a Facebook App-ID,i don't know how to make "login with Facebook" function